# How to define .done()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement call of deffered `done` function, but can't find a way to do that:

```
jQuery.fn.imageload=function(src) {
    $this=$(this);
    var img=new Image();
    img.src=src;
    if (img.complete) {done();return;}
    img.onload=done;
    function done() {
        console.log('done');
        $this.empty().append(img);
    }
    return $this;
}

$('div').imageload('http://placehold.it/350x150').done(function() {
    //this not called
    console.log('done loading');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/m4jvd/

What should I add to plugin declaration to call `.done()` after image has been loaded ?

Comment: Not related to `.done` or deferred, but this fragment won't work in some versions of IE. To fix IE, you need to set `src` *after* setting `onload`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hnhGR/3/

You need to use the [jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object.

```
$(function () {
    $.fn.imageload=function(src) {
        $this=$(this);
        var img=new Image();
        img.src=src;
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        img.onload = function() {
            deferred.resolve(img); 
        }
        if (img.complete) {
            img.onload();
        }
        deferred.done(function () {
            console.log('done');
            $this.empty().append(img);
            return img;
        });
        return deferred;
    }

    $('#my-div').imageload('http://placehold.it/350x150').done(function(img) {
        console.log('done loading', img);
    });
});
```

Basically the Deferred object has a `resolve()` method. When this is fired it means whatever asynchronous process that was taking place has finished. When the resolve is fired, all callbacks that are assigned with `done()` and `then()` are called in sequence. The value you pass to the `resolve()` method is passed to these callbacks (in this case, the `img` variable).

Comment: Not sure I get this, but how does this fire when the image has loaded?

Comment: I know how a deferred object works, but your not resolving it when the image has loaded, only on complete? If img.complete does'nt fire, how do you know when the image has loaded without an onload function ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
jQuery.fn.imageload = function(src) {
    var self = this,
        img = new Image(),
        def = new jQuery.Deferred();

    if (img.complete) {
        def.resolve();
    }
    img.onload = function() {
        console.log('done');
        self.empty().append(img);
        def.resolve(); 
    }
    img.src = src;
    return def.promise();
}

$('div').imageload('http://placehold.it/350x150').done(function() {
    console.log('done loading');
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/guu6z/ seems not works, `def` `has no method 'resolve' `

Comment: @eicto - There's actually been a change in 1.9, where you now construct a new Deferred instead, so try the above code.

Comment: You need to call Deferred(). At the moment it's a reference to that function.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make use of [$.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). I guess this would work:

```
$.fn.imageload = function(src) {
    $this = this;
    return $.Deferred(function() {
        var self = this,
            img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
           $this.empty().append(img);
           self.resolve();
        };
        img.src = src;
    });
}

$('div').imageload('http://placehold.it/350x150').done(function () {
    console.log('done loading');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k6kuB/